# Precautions to avoid adulterated handful of meal offering

Tags: maseches-menachos, mincha-meal-offering, temple-service-avoda

According to the Mishna ([Menachot 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Menachot.1.2?lang=bi)), when the Kohen extracts the representative *kometz*-handful from a *mincha* (meal offering), any foreign objects, such as a pebble, a chunk of salt, or a bit of frankincense, are included in the handful, the offering is invalidated.

It seems like it would be a big shame to waste an offering, especially if it was a special communal one like the Omer, over an errant bit of spice.

Did the kohanim have any standard practices to prevent such an invalidation from happening? Did they do any sifting or inspections of the whole offering or of the material they'd take the handful from?

Comment: "especially if it was a special communal one like the Omer" https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.5

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

[Menachot 6:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Menachot.6.7?lang=bi) teaches that the flour used for the Omer, Shtei Halechem and Lechem Hapanim was sifted many times before use.

While (presumably) this was done in order to fulfil the requirement to use *solet* (fine flour) in these offerings, I would imagine that a side benefit would be to reduce (although not eliminate) the possibility of extraneous matter invalidating them.